# Ionic 4 vs Angular 6 (+Material) - For PWA with emphasis on SSR

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

** Cross posting from https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-vs-angular-6-material-for-pwa-with-emphasis-on-ssr/126926 **

I have built a PWA (https://alpha3.grassrootsapp.in/2) in Ionic 3. I have couple of open issues with URL Routing:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/133293
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/127652

It’s been ages since I am waiting for Ionic 4, with promised fixes for Routing and better PWA support. But we are yet to see Ionic 4 alpha version. And I guess, it will take 2-3 or even more months to see Ionic 4 Stable version.

Also one another new requirement for me now is SSR. I want my whole app to be crawled and get indexed in Google. I understand Stencil supports SSR, but couldn’t find any authentic news on Ionic 4 SSR support.

I am thinking If I should rewrite my App as pure Angular 6 application, so I can get SSR. I guess I need to completely rewrite my templates using Angular material, while retaining the app code that resides in components and providers.

Would like to hear opinions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Unfortunately, StackOverflow is NOT for opinion based, open ended discussions.

Comment: Why did you choose ionic for your application? How's your userbase? The main goal of ionic is to build an app in a webcontainer (cordova) while angular will provide you a pure web solution while still being a PWA. The answer depends on your userbase

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes. Expected that. I am just looking for Expert advice. Not any specific solution.
Supamiu I originally made Android App with Ionic, but later decided to switch to PWA. Since UI Layer is very good with Ionic and Ionic 4/StencilJS looks promising, but dont have a clear roadmap, I am in a dilemma now